# How to pass multiple Selectors in UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

This is my code for a back button.
I have 9 buttons (button1,button2...button9)
And i want this button to activate if i press any of the other 9 buttons.
So is there a way where i can do this?

```
[_backButtonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(button1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: You want a fake button press (UI) or just the other button action method to be called?

Comment: I want the _backButtonOutlet to be called  when i press any of the other buttons

Comment: Means you want to call 9 buttons event on the click of any button.

Answer (score 0):

Create some method with will call all the desired methods that you want to call at the same time and call that method on button tapped event. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction) button1:(id)sender
{
      [self btn1Pressed:sender];
      [self btn2Pressed:sender];
      [self btn3Pressed:sender];
      [self btn4Pressed:sender];
      [self btn5Pressed:sender];
      [self btn6Pressed:sender];
      [self btn7Pressed:sender];
      [self btn8Pressed:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`_backButtonOutlet` is a reference to the button so you don't want it to be called when any buttons are pressed. `button1:` is the method that you want to be called when any button is pressed.

Option 1:

call:

```
[otherButtonOutlet_N addTarget:self action:@selector(button1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

on each of the other buttons (replace `otherButtonOutlet_N` as appropriate).

Option 2:

In your XIB / storyboard, connect all of the buttons to the `button1:` method. You can add multiple target/action pairs to a button.